# Deep Linking In Roku SDK using RSS Feeds

Tags: rss, deep-linking, roku, brightscript

Having trouble getting deep linking to work in my Roku channel.

I've done a lot of reading on the Roku SDK (particularly their Deep Linking Doc) and a variety of forums. However, I'm just not making any headway.

Currently, my channel uses the Simple Grid with Details template, which serves video content via RSS files.

Here's the beginning of my main.brs file:

```
sub Main(args as Dynamic) as Void

showSGScreen(args)

 if (args.mediaType <> invalid) and (args.contentID <> invalid)
if (args.mediaType = "movie" or args.mediaType = "episode" or args.mediaType = "short-form" or args.mediaType = "series" or args.mediaType = "special")
    'play content directly
else
    'deep linking issue such as a contentID not matching any content in the partner's catalog
    'display an appropriate error message for the user
end if
else
'launch channel normally
end if

end sub

Sub RunUserInterface()
screen = CreateObject("roSGScreen")
scene = screen.CreateScene("HomeScene")
port = CreateObject("roMessagePort")
screen.SetMessagePort(port)
screen.Show()

oneRow = GetApiArray1()
twoRow = GetApiArray2()
threeRow = GetApiArray3()
fourRow = GetApiArray4()

list = [
{
    TITLE : "Watch Our Services Live"
    ContentList : oneRow
}
{
    TITLE : "Without Ceasing: A Series On Prayer"
    ContentList : twoRow
}
{
    TITLE : "The Least Of These: Hope, Help, Heal"
    ContentList : threeRow
}
{
    TITLE : "The Bible: Learning To Live It"
    ContentList : fourRow
}


]
scene.gridContent = ParseXMLContent(list)

while true
    msg = wait(0, port)
    print "------------------"
    print "msg = "; msg
end while

if screen <> invalid then
    screen.Close()
    screen = invalid
end if
End Sub


Function ParseXMLContent(list As Object)
RowItems = createObject("RoSGNode","ContentNode")

for each rowAA in list
'for index = 0 to 1
    row = createObject("RoSGNode","ContentNode")
    row.Title = rowAA.Title

    for each itemAA in rowAA.ContentList
        item = createObject("RoSGNode","ContentNode")
        ' We don't use item.setFields(itemAA) as doesn't cast 
streamFormat to proper value
        for each key in itemAA
            item[key] = itemAA[key]
        end for
        row.appendChild(item)
    end for
    RowItems.appendChild(row)
end for

return RowItems
End Function


Function GetApiArray1()
url = CreateObject("roUrlTransfer")
url.SetUrl("http://media.genepensiero.com/roku/rss/livestream.rss")
rsp = url.GetToString()

responseXML = ParseXML(rsp)
responseXML = responseXML.GetChildElements()
responseArray = responseXML.GetChildElements()

result = []

for each xmlItem in responseArray
    if xmlItem.getName() = "item"
        itemAA = xmlItem.GetChildElements()
        if itemAA <> invalid
            item = {}
            for each xmlItem in itemAA
                item[xmlItem.getName()] = xmlItem.getText()
                if xmlItem.getName() = "media:content"
                    item.stream = {url : xmlItem.url}
                    item.url = xmlItem.getAttributes().url
                    item.streamFormat = "hls"

                    mediaContent = xmlItem.GetChildElements()
                    for each mediaContentItem in mediaContent
                        if mediaContentItem.getName() = 
 "media:thumbnail"
                            item.HDPosterUrl = 
mediaContentItem.getattributes().url
                            item.hdBackgroundImageUrl = 
mediaContentItem.getattributes().url
                        end if
                    end for
                end if
            end for
            result.push(item)
        end if
    end if
end for

return result
End Function
```

Then an example of my RSS feed is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rss xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/" version="2.0">
<channel>
    <title>Bright Light Church</title>
    <link />
    <description>Live and Archived Bible Studies</description>
    <language>en-us</language>
    <pubDate>Wed, 26 Apr 2017 12:00:00 PT</pubDate>
    <category>TV &amp; Film</category>
    <image>
        <title>The Bible</title>
        <url>http://media.genepensiero.com/roku/withoutceasing.jpg</url>
        <width>-1</width>
        <height>-1</height>
    </image>


<item>
<title>Prayer Pressure</title>
<link>http://media.calvaryhanford.com/psalms/prayerpressure.mp4</link>
<description>David brings big requests to God and receives a big 
revelation.</description>
<pubDate>Sun, 05 Mar 2017 10:15:00 PT</pubDate>
<guid isPermaLink="false">ch001</guid>
<media:content channels="2" type="special" isDefault="true" id="ch001"  url="http://media.calvaryhanford.com/psalms/prayerpressure.mp4">
<media:description>David brings big requests to God and receives a big 
revelation.</media:description>
<media:keywords>church, bible study, expository sermon</media:keywords>
<media:thumbnail url="http://media.genepensiero.com/roku/withoutceasing.jpg" />
<media:title>Prayer Pressure</media:title>
</media:content>
</item>
```

When I use the Deep Link Tester it just opens my channel to the home screen, it doesn't launch the specific video.

Any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to be doing anything with the `contentID` and `mediaType`, the app will not deeplink to content automatically (or magically). You'll have to match the received `contentId` to an item in your API, and navigate to or play that item (depending on the `mediaType`), all from within your app.